# Make a DATETIME column show red background 2 hours after duedate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column

So I got this code, it makes the background green when it has passed the set taskduedate. But I want it to show red background when it has passed 2 hours after taskduedate, it that possible?

```
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "debugMode": true,
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0, if([$TaskDueDate] <= @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50'), '')"
      }
    }
```

All with red circles should be red when the clock is 19:00

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. It will made the background green if the due date hasn't passed yet and will make it normal for up to 2 hours after it has passed, then red after 2 hours after the due date.

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "debugMode": true,
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0, if([$TaskDueDate] <= @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50', if(Number(@now) >= (Number([$TaskDueDate])+1000*60*60*2),'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50', '')), '')"
      }
    }
```

Comment: This wont work, it makes everything green even if the time in the column has passed 2 hours. So I got a column that says "2020-04-09 15:23" and the time right now is "2020-04-09 19:05 " then the column should be red because it was over 2 hours ago. Or else it should be green. I appreciate yout help!

Comment: Is the timezone of the site collection match that of the client (you)? The value of [$TaskDueDate] without formatting will reflect the site collection's timezone. However, it will be converted to the client's timezone in formatting as will @now. This can make things pretty confusing.

Comment: Yes, it works with other formats.

Comment: I've edited my question with a picture

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below json code:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "debugMode": true,
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0, if([$TaskDueDate] <= @now + 7200000, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50', if([$TaskDueDate] <= @now,'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50','')), '')"
      }
 }
```